# Bicep Loop over key vault keys and encrypt storage account

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-storage-account, azure-bicep

I have a bit of a huge blocker here about the implementation logic.

I am working with bicep to create those resources.

- storage accounts
- key vault
- pass storage accounts connection string to key vault secrets
- create a key in key vault and encrypt storage account with that key.

The first Three steps are done. if I declare 2 storage accounts, it will create automatically 2 secrets connection strings and 2 keys. All the pairing (storage name and connection string) they match.

Now the issue I am facing is the following, to start with, this is my code.

```
param tenantCode array = [
  'dsec'
  'sdre'
]

var storageName = [for item in tenantCode :{
  name: string('sthrideveur${item}')
}]


var connectionStringSecretName = [for connection in storageName :{
  name: '${connection.name}'
  
}]

output connectionStringSecretName array= [for connection in storageName :{
  name: '${connection.name}'
  
}]






resource storage_Accounts 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts@2021-06-01' = [ for name in storageName :{
  name: '${name.name}'
  location: 'westeurope'
  sku: {
    name: 'Standard_RAGRS'
  }
  kind: 'StorageV2'
  properties: {
    allowCrossTenantReplication: true
    minimumTlsVersion: 'TLS1_2'
    allowBlobPublicAccess: false
    allowSharedKeyAccess: true
    networkAcls: {
      bypass: 'AzureServices'
      virtualNetworkRules: []
      ipRules: []
      defaultAction: 'Allow'
    }
    supportsHttpsTrafficOnly: true
    encryption: {
      services: {
        file: {
          keyType: 'Account'
          enabled: true
        }
        blob: {
          keyType: 'Account'
          enabled: true
        }
      }
      keySource: 'Microsoft.Storage'
      keyvaultproperties: { 
        keyname: '${tenantKey[0]}'
        keyvaulturi: keyVault.id
      }
    }
    accessTier: 'Cool'
  }
}]

resource keyVault 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults@2019-09-01' existing = {
  name : 'XXX'
}

// Store the connection string in KV if specified
resource storageAccountConnectionString 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/secrets@2019-09-01' = [for name in storageName :{
  name: '${keyVault.name}/${name.name}'
  properties: {
    value: 'DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=${storage_Accounts[0].name};AccountKey=${listKeys('${storage_Accounts[0].id}', '${storage_Accounts[0].apiVersion}').keys[0].value};EndpointSuffix=${environment().suffixes.storage}'
  }
}]

resource tenantKey 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/keys@2021-06-01-preview' = [for tenant in tenantCode : {
  name: '${keyVault.name}/Client-Key-${tenant}'
  properties: {
    keySize: 2048
    kty: 'RSA'
  }
  
}]
```

I have 2 storage account I want to create. And the keys, contains the storage code. What I want to do and I am having problem to implement, is how to match the correct key with the correct storage account. In this specific case, I have to codes as follow:

```
dsec
sdre
```

The bicep script will create 2 storage accounts and secrets named accordingly:

```
sthrideveurdsec
sthrideveursdre

AND 2 secrets with the same name
sthrideveurdsec
sthrideveursdre

AND 2 Keys named
Client-Key-dsec
Client-Key-sdre
```

What I would to do, is to encrypt the storage account DSEC with key DSEC and the storage SDRE with the key SDRE. But as I am new to bicep I am having some problem to implement this.

If anyone can help me to understand how to achieve this correct pairing I would be grateful.

UPDATE:
After testing Thomas solution, this is the error I am getting:

```
{"status":"Failed","error":{"code":"DeploymentFailed","message":"At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/DeployOperations for usage details.","details":[{"code":"BadRequest","message":"{\r\n  \"error\": {\r\n    \"code\": \"KeyVaultPolicyError\",\r\n    \"message\": \"Keyvault policy recoverable is not set\"\r\n  }\r\n}"},{"code":"BadRequest","message":"{\r\n  \"error\": {\r\n    \"code\": \"KeyVaultPolicyError\",\r\n    \"message\": \"Keyvault policy recoverable is not set\"\r\n  }\r\n}"}]}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming the key vault is created and uses access policies.

If you'd like to create the storage with customer-managed keys, the storage needs to get access to key vault before it is created so I'm using a user assigned identity in my sample.

Here are the steps:

- Create a managed identity and grant key permissions on key vault
- Create the two keys in key vault
- Create the storage, assign the managed identity and use the key for encryption

```bicep
// Default values I'm using to test 
param location string = resourceGroup().location
param keyVaultName string = 'kvthomastest'
param managedIdentityName string = 'mi-storage-encryption-thomas-test'

param tenantCodes array = [
  'dsec'
  'sdre'
]

// I'm using prefix so I dont need to create additional arrays
var keyVaultKeyPrefix = 'Client-Key-'
var storagePrefix = 'stthomastest'

// Get a reference to key vault
resource keyVault 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults@2021-06-01-preview' existing = {
  name: keyVaultName
}

// Create a managed identity
resource managedIdentity 'Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities@2018-11-30' = {
  name: managedIdentityName
  location: location
}

// Grant permissions to key vault
resource accessPolicy 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/accessPolicies@2019-09-01' = {
  name: 'add'
  parent: keyVault
  properties: {
    accessPolicies: [
      {
        tenantId: subscription().tenantId
        objectId: managedIdentity.properties.principalId
        permissions: {
          // minimum required permissions
          keys: [
            'get'
            'unwrapKey'
            'wrapKey'
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}

// Create key vault keys
resource keyVaultKeys 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/keys@2021-06-01-preview' = [for tenantCode in tenantCodes: {
  name: '${keyVaultKeyPrefix}${tenantCode}'
  parent: keyVault
  properties: {
    keySize: 2048
    kty: 'RSA'
    // storage key should only needs these operations
    keyOps: [
      'unwrapKey'
      'wrapKey'
    ]
  }
}]

// Create storage accounts
resource storageAccount 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts@2021-04-01' = [for tenantCode in tenantCodes: {
  name: '${storagePrefix}${tenantCode}'
  location: location
  kind: 'StorageV2'
  sku: {
    name: 'Standard_RAGRS'
  }
  // Assign the identity
  identity: {
    type: 'UserAssigned'
    userAssignedIdentities: {
      '${managedIdentity.id}': {}
    }
  }
  properties: {
    allowCrossTenantReplication: true
    minimumTlsVersion: 'TLS1_2'
    allowBlobPublicAccess: false
    allowSharedKeyAccess: true
    networkAcls: {
      bypass: 'AzureServices'
      virtualNetworkRules: []
      ipRules: []
      defaultAction: 'Allow'
    }
    supportsHttpsTrafficOnly: true
    encryption: {
      identity: {
        // specify which identity to use
        userAssignedIdentity: managedIdentity.id
      }
      keySource: 'Microsoft.Keyvault'
      keyvaultproperties: {
        keyname: '${keyVaultKeyPrefix}${tenantCode}'
        keyvaulturi: keyVault.properties.vaultUri
      }
      services: {
        file: {
          keyType: 'Account'
          enabled: true
        }
        blob: {
          keyType: 'Account'
          enabled: true
        }
      }
    }
    accessTier: 'Cool'
  }
}]
```

Comment: thank you very much for your time and help.  I tried your code, but I get an error, I will update my post with the error.

Comment: are you using the same key vault name as  me ? i ve just deleted it and you wont be able to recreate it

Comment: you need to set the keyVaultName and managedIdentityName parameters to match whatever you want as name

Comment: No I did changed the both the managedIdentity AND the KeyvaultName

Comment: I found the issue. The key vault should have enabled the Purge protection. Can I just ask you a question please before to vote your answer. I see that you created a managed identity. Is that required for the script to be able to access the key vault? what are the differences between creating the azure managed identity and just give the 'systemAssigned' to the resource that needs to access the key vault?

Comment: if you using system assigned identity, you need to create first the storage then configure the encryption, a chicken and egg probelm ^^ if you use a user assigned identity you can create the identity, grant permission then create the storage in one go.